# Django access m2m model value in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So I want to make habit tracking web page, I have 3 models (habits are called category)

```
class Day(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    date = models.DateField()

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categoryBD = models.ManyToManyField(Day, through='CategoryByDay')

class CategoryByDay(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

As you can see it's rather simple. To get track of what I did this specific day I connect each category with each new day.

Now I managed to put some neat buttons next to each category and even got jquery magic to make ajax request when each button is clicked and to hide each button and update status. However, when I refresh the page I still get all the buttons.

So I need to check in the template, if the category this day has a created CategoryByDay model, and if the status is set to 0 or 1.

Can I do it throught template syntax?
It would require some strange querying. I pass to my template today's date and list of categories. Maybe I should expand the list of categories to add a status here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need a name for your Day class, but anyway all three classes can be done in one simple class:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    status = models.BooleanField()
```

Next you want to check what have been done at specific date? Simply make a query:

```
categorybyday = Category.objects.filter(date=your_date)
```

Comment: But this way, if I specify a category say "Go Jogging" and add a date to it, it will be one time check. I want to check if I did some things everyday and log a status, so "Go Jogging" in 17/2/14 is 1 (I went running) but "Go Jogging" in 15/2/14 is 0. So, I need m2m relation

Comment: You can add status to the model I wrote (look at edited first post) and just change it when it was done.

Comment: Let's say I have 10 categories I want to log in a span of 300 days. That would require me to make 3000 categories instances. (10*day) I don't think you follow me, I want to log it repeatedly, not just in one specific day.

Comment: In your solution you would have 3000 instances of m2m relations and strange queries.